# Can cloud function use any of composer environment variables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-composer

We have 160 Cloud Functions (CF) setup and in the CF code we have to refer to the webserved id and client id of the composer where the CF should run. Currently its hardcoded.
Is there any way by which we can access environment variables of Cloud Composer or any other place where common config values can be stored and referred used in the CF.

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?

Comment: Hi @ks_baba, Is the above comment helpful?

Comment: Hi @ks_baba, You can refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#deploy_a_cloud_function_that_triggers_the_dag) to Deploy a Cloud Function that triggers the DAG. Let me know it's helpful or not?